# Change the element wrapping its children based on a condition in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I wasn't sure how to title this question, but I'm basically wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this:

```
var inputElement;
if(props.horizontal){
     inputElement = <div className="col-sm-10">
        {props.children}
        {help}
    </div>
} else {
    inputElement = <span className="col-sm-10">
        {props.children}
        {help}
    </span>
}
```

Based on whether `props.vertical` is `true`, I'm wrapping `{props.children}` and `{help}` in a span or a div. Is there a clean way to do this without repeating `{props.children}{help}` twice? Is there a way to put the type of element I want in a variable, and then use that in jsx to wrap these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React Elements can be constructed [either from a Component, or a string representing an HTML tag](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement).

That means, an approach like the the following works perfectly fine:

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const wrapper = props.horizontal ? 'div' : 'span'
  return <wrapper className="col-sm-10">Content</wrapper>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App horizontal={true} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```